# Gnuplot with data from sqlite3 (using multiple columns)

Tags: sqlite, gnuplot

i got the following problem:
I habe a sqlite3 database with the following columns:
ID, tempin, tempout, humidity, time, date

Now i want to plot all the content into a nice plot using gnuplot.
I searched a little and found the following code:

```
plot '< sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT temp1, temp2, pressure, humidity FROM myTable;"' using 0:1 title 'temp1', \
     '' using 0:2 title 'temp2'
```

But after editing it, the gnuplot said "Warning: Skipping data file with no valid points"

My database looks like:

```
ID    tempin      tempout     humidity     date         time
1     24          12          55           01.11.2014   07:00
2     23          13          54           01.11.2014   07:15
3     25          13          45           01.11.2014   07:30
```

Does anyone have an idea why i cant plot the database into gnuplot?
And furthermore i want to use the column date or time for x scale.

Comment: Can you post the exact output of `sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT temp1, temp2, pressure, humidity FROM myTable;"` when you type it in a terminal (no gnuplot involved)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

1. the column names in the gnuplot code do not match those in the
   database
2. sqlite3 by default uses `|` as delimiter between data columns, but gnuplot by default expects whitespace

To reproduce your problem, I typed into sqlite3

```
create table myTable ( id int, tempin int, tempout int, humidity int, date date, time time );
insert into myTable values ( 1, 24, 12, 55, "01.11.2014", "07:00" );
insert into myTable values ( 2, 23, 13, 54, "01.11.2014", "07:15" );
insert into myTable values ( 3, 25, 13, 45, "01.11.2014", "07:30" );
```

and then tried your query

```
select temp1, temp2, pressure, humidity from myTable;
```

and got

```
Error: no such column: temp1
```

Then I tried

```
select * from myTable;
```

and got

```
1|24|12|55|01.11.2014|07:00
2|23|13|54|01.11.2014|07:15
3|25|13|45|01.11.2014|07:30
```

Hence, my working gnuplot code suggestion for your database is

```
set datafile separator '|'
plot '< sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT tempin, tempout FROM myTable;"' using 0:1 title 'temp1', \
 '' using 0:2 title 'temp2'
```

Answer (score -2):

Directly behind the word `plot`, a source, e.g. a filename is needed expected, not the data itself. However, you can use the special filename "-" and gnuplot will ask you to enter a table manually. It looks like this:

```
gnuplot> plot "-" u 1:2 w l
input data ('e' ends) > 
ID    tempin      tempout     humidity     date        time
1     24          12          55           01.11.2014   07:00
2     23          13          54           01.11.2014   07:15
3     25          13          45           01.11.2014   07:30
input data ('e' ends) > e
```

Now, it depends on the way you call gnuplot.  From a commandline, you can call

```
gnuplot -e "plot '-' u 1:2 w l" <  sqlite3 myfile.db3 ...
```

I myself are not a friend of passing data directly to gnuplot. I prefer to write it to a file, first:

```
sqlite3 myfile.db3 ... > myDataFile

gnuplot -e "plot 'myDataFile' u 1:2 w l"
```

Even then, I prefer to write a gnuplot script containing all commands for gnuplot. As the number of settings increases, the single command line becomes longer and less readable.

Comment: This question is not about how to run `sqlite3` (`<` works just fine), but how to get `gnuplot` to recognize its output format.

Comment: OK, I acknowledge that. Didn't know that `<...` also works as filename. However, the code works for me (using a dummy-sql-script which prints the table to stdout). So, either sqlite does not do what is expected, or there is another problem with the gnuplot code. As the gnuplot code consists of a single line, I guess that there is something wrong with the sqlite call.